# BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returns NULL

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to get a pic just made it with the cam with the next code, but I have always the same error:

```
 skia(446): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

(It doesn't throw an exception). So the object bitmap is always NULL and I can't see the pic just made it with the cam, and which I can see it with the File Explorer from Eclipse.

What happened? How can I fix this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_photo);        
    ImageView imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.foto);
    try {
        Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,   null, null, null,null); 
        String str = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        cur.moveToLast();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + str);
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in, 24);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
        if (bMap != null)
            imagen.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        else{
            Log.d("onCreate: ", "bMap es NULL");
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            Log.d("onCreate: ", "in cerrado");
        }
        if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
            Log.d("onCreate: ", "buf cerrado");
        }
        Log.d("onCreate: ", "Fin del proceso");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
    }           

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following things:

```
     // get the SD Card path, you need to check first if this is available
     File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

     // I am assuming str is your filename, make sure you are getting the right value for this one
     File file = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath(), str);

     // Note that the buffer size is in bytes, so 24 in your question is very low
     BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in, 8192);
     Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
```